# Remove the specific object from array and shift this object on 0 index of the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array which has multiple objects. I just want to remove a object by using comparing the title and shift this object on 0 index at the same array. How can I do it. Please suggest me the solution.

**Input Array:**

```
 const inputArr = [{id:1, title:"John",age:20},{id:2, title:"smith",age:22},{id:3, title:"stokes",age:24},{id:4, title:"david",age:30},{id:5, title:"William",age:28},{id:6, title:"Andy",age:32}]
```

**Output Array:**

```
const outputArr = [{id:5, title:"William",age:28},{id:1, title:"John",age:20},{id:2, title:"smith",age:22},{id:3, title:"stokes",age:24},{id:4, title:"david",age:30},{id:6, title:"Andy",age:32}]
```

Remove the object with title===William from array and shift into the 0 index

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use sort for that

```js
const inputArr = [{id:1, title:"John",age:20},{id:2, title:"smith",age:22},{id:3, title:"stokes",age:24},{id:4, title:"david",age:30},{id:5, title:"William",age:28},{id:6, title:"Andy",age:32}]


const outputArray =  [...inputArr].sort((a, b) => {
  if(a.title === 'William') return -1
  if(b.title === 'William') return 1
  return a.id - b.id
})


console.log(outputArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const inputArr = [{id:1, title:"John",age:20},{id:2, title:"smith",age:22},{id:3, title:"stokes",age:24},{id:4, title:"david",age:30},{id:5, title:"William",age:28},{id:6, title:"Andy",age:32}];

// `findIndex` of the appropriate object
const index = inputArr.findIndex(obj => obj.title === 'William');

// `splice` out the object and then `unshift` it
// to the start of the array (Note: we don't have
// to make any changes if the index is 0)
if (index > 0) {
  inputArr.unshift(inputArr.splice(index, 1));
}

console.log(inputArr);
```

Additional documentation

- [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

Answer (score 0):

```
const inputArr = [{id:1, title:"John",age:20},{id:2, title:"smith",age:22},{id:3, title:"stokes",age:24},{id:4, title:"david",age:30},{id:5, title:"William",age:28},{id:6, title:"Andy",age:32}]
    
    const getTitle = inputArr.filter((item) => item.title === 'William')
    const getRest = inputArr.filter((item) => item.title !== 'William')
    
    
    console.log(getTitle.concat(getRest))
```